# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 933 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)

Tags: php, html

I want to update a value in a table and it keeps showing me the same message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 933 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)

Code:

```
function modificarEstado($conexion, $nif,$email) {

    if(devolverEstadoconEmail($conexion, $email)=='Activo'){ 
        try { 
            $consulta = ("UPDATE CLIENTE SET ACTIVOBAJA='ACTIVO' WHERE DNI_CLIENTE=$nif"); 
            $stmt = $conexion -> prepare($consulta); 
            $stmt -> execute(); 
            echo $stmt -> debugDumpParams(); 
            return true; 
        } catch(PDOException $e) { 
            $_SESSION['excepcion'] = $e -> GetMessage(); 
            echo $_SESSION['excepcion']; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: function modificarEstado($conexion, $nif,$email) {
 if(devolverEstadoconEmail($conexion, $email)=='Activo'){
  
 try {
  $consulta = ("UPDATE CLIENTE SET ACTIVOBAJA='ACTIVO' WHERE DNI_CLIENTE=$nif");
  $stmt = $conexion -> prepare($consulta);
  $stmt -> execute();
  echo $stmt -> debugDumpParams();
  return true;
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  $_SESSION['excepcion'] = $e -> GetMessage();
  echo $_SESSION['excepcion'];
 }
 }

Comment: UPDATE CLIENTE SET ACTIVOBAJA='ACTIVO' WHERE DNI_CLIENTE='$nif'" Try this

Comment: Don't post code in comments

Comment: Your main problem is the use of `DNI_CLIENTE=$nif`.  This is a performance issue and big security risk.  Use bind variables instead.  Check the PDO documentation for examples.